# Return query results based on 2 parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that accepts 2 parameters of type varchar.  The default value is just an empty string, but if not, then it's a list/array of numbers as defined below.

I'm trying to come  up with a query that will account for either parameter being empty or actually containing something.

What I have below, isn't returning everything if the parameters are empty.

If they are both empty, then I want the query to run as if I just did this:

```
SELECT TOP(200) * FROM @ResultsTable
```

If either one is not empty then it needs to run against the list like:

```
SELECT TOP(200) * FROM @ResultsTable
WHERE engineGroup IN(5, 4, 9, 11)

--AND if the other one is not empty too:

AND modelYear IN(2007, 2009, 2015)
```

Here is the query:

```
    --PARAMETERS    
  @engineGroup AS VARCHAR(8000) = '',          --default to '' if null
  @modelYear AS VARCHAR(8000) = ''     --default to '' if null


 --@engineGroup is either '' or a grouping like (5, 4, 9, 11)
 --@modelYear is either '' or a group like (2005, 2012, 2015) 


SELECT  TOP(200) *
FROM    @ResultsTable
    WHERE
        @engineGroup = ''
    OR
        engineGroup IN(@engineGroup)
    AND 
        @modelYear = ''
    OR
        modelYear IN(@modelYear )
```

I do get results, but it seems as if I don't have the AND/OR logic correct.

It seems to be returning data like I did an OR statement between the two parameters instead of an AND statement.

Is there a better way to structure this?

Thanks

Comment: here is a good link that you should use [SQL Basics Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm) also I would look up the `ISNULL` function and understand how to utilize it as well as how it works, after that I would read up on `Out Params` in Sql I would also read up on how to formulate `AND query , OR query as well as mixing AND with OR` this can cause you many headaches if you do not know how to logically formulate a proper conditional sql clause in regards to `Filtering`

Comment: if @engineGroup is a list of values like '1,2,3' you can't do engineGroup IN(@engineGroup) - IN doesn't work that way.

Comment: You might want to look up table valued parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this should work - however using multiple IF statements should result in better performance (at least from my experience).
One query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @ResultTable
WHERE (engineGroup IN (@engineGroup) OR NULLIF(@engineGroup, '') IS NULL)
    AND (modelYear = @modelYear OR NULLIF(@modelYear, '') IS NULL)
```

Multiple IFs:

```
IF @engineGroup IS NOT NULL AND @modelYear IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (200) *
    FROM @ResultsTable
    WHERE engineGroup = @engineGroup
        AND modelYear = @modelYear
END
ELSE IF @engineGroup IS NOT NULL AND @modelYear IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (200) *
    FROM @ResultsTable
    WHERE engineGroup = @engineGroup
END
ELSE IF @engineGroup IS NULL AND @modelYear IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (200) *
    FROM @ResultsTable
    WHERE modelYear = @modelYear
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (200) *
    FROM @ResultsTable
END
```